# How to dismiss current view and reload another?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

```
@IBAction func DoneButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as UIViewController
    viewController.viewWillAppear()
}
```

Its suppose to dismiss my current view and reload ViewController

but it crashes with fatal error: unexpectedly

```
found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

is it because I'm dismissing before?

Comment: what do you mean by 'reload'? Reload implies that you want to load an existing view controller...again. Your code is instantiating a new view controller, not reloading one.

Comment: if you want to present a new view controller after dismissing your current one, simply present the controller your instantiating.  it would be essential to present from the completion block of you dismiss action.

Comment: I got it working using option 3 (see below)

Comment: Actually option 3 doesn't actually execute the reloadRoutineData() when the done button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking to do either

1.

```
    let viewController = ViewController()

    viewController.viewWillAppear(false)
```

2.

In secondary class:

```
    let viewController = ViewController()

    viewController.shouldRefresh = true
```

In primary class:

```
var shouldRefresh: Bool!

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if shouldRefresh == true {

    }
}
```

3.

In secondary class:

```
    let viewController = ViewController()

    viewController.reloadRoutineData()
```

In primary class:

```
func reloadRoutineData() {

// Do my stuff here 
}
```

The third option is my variable because I only need to do certain code, not really reload the view completely. But all of them crash with nil while unwrapping.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier()` returns an optional. So if the view controller with the specified identifier cannot be found in your storyboard, it will be set to nil and the next line where you call `viewWillAppear` will crash.

It is also possible that you crash inside `viewWillAppear` actually. That is not a method that *you* should call. Instead, UIKit will call that method for you when your view controller is presented.

I guess what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
if let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as UIViewController {
    self.presentViewController(viewController,
        animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

If not, provide more context to your question.